# Pandas: use map function to LOOKUP a value in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to use the map function to update values in `df1` based on the looked up value in `df2`The lookup column is `ISIN_CUSIP_CODE`

```
df1 = [('ISIN_CUSIP_CODE', ['US68323ABL70', '9128284D9', '912828W89', 'CA135087J470','CA135087J470','912796QP7','US20030NCM11','US912810SD19','XS1851277969',]),
                ('Product', ['GOVT', 'GOVT', 'GOVT', 'GOVT', 'GOVT', 'GOVT', '', '', '',]),        
                 ]    
        df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(df1)
        print(df1)
df2 = [('ISIN_CUSIP_CODE', ['US20030NCM11', 'US912810SD19', 'XS1851277969', 'XS1391086987', 'CA064151BL66', 'CA13595ZZ661', ]),
                ('Product_MRD', ['CORP', 'GOVT', 'CORP', 'CORP','CORP','CORP',]),
                 ]    
        df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(df2)
        print(df2)

df1
  ISIN_CUSIP_CODE Product
0    US68323ABL70    GOVT
1       9128284D9    GOVT
2       912828W89    GOVT
3    CA135087J470    GOVT
4    CA135087J470    GOVT
5       912796QP7    GOVT
6    US20030NCM11        
7    US912810SD19        
8    XS1851277969        
 df2
  ISIN_CUSIP_CODE Product_MRD
0    US20030NCM11        CORP
1    US912810SD19        GOVT
2    XS1851277969        CORP
3    XS1391086987        CORP
4    CA064151BL66        CORP
5    CA13595ZZ661        CORP
```

My map function is not returning the looked up values in `df2`

```
df1['Product'].map(df2.set_index('ISIN_CUSIP_CODE')['Product_MRD'])
print(df1)

  ISIN_CUSIP_CODE Product
0    US68323ABL70    GOVT
1       9128284D9    GOVT
2       912828W89    GOVT
3    CA135087J470    GOVT
4    CA135087J470    GOVT
5       912796QP7    GOVT
6    US20030NCM11        
7    US912810SD19        
8    XS1851277969
```

Comment: Typo: use `df1['ISIN_CUSIP_CODE'].map(df2.set_index('ISIN_CUSIP_CODE')['Product_MRD'])`

Comment: Use `np.where(df1['Product'].replace('',np.nan).isnull(),df1['ISIN_CUSIP_CODE'].map(df2.set_index('ISIN_CUSIP_CODE')['Product_MRD']),df1['Product'])`

Comment: Getting NameError: name 'np' is not defined. Does np need to be prefixed/

Comment: `import numpy as np`

Comment: Sorry  same result

Comment: if assign dfTest = df1['ISIN_CUSIP_CODE'].map(df2.set_index('ISIN_CUSIP_CODE')['Product_MRD']). I can see the last three Products. Just need to update df1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution using partial.

```
from functools import partial
def lookup(row, lookup_df):
    try:
        return lookup_df[lookup_df.ISIN_CUSIP_CODE == row['ISIN_CUSIP_CODE']].Product_MRD.values[0]
    except:
        return row['Product']
df1['ProductLooked'] = df1.apply(partial(lookup, lookup_df=df2), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Federico Pucci. Was not aware of this library at all. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome! It's quite useful as well in case you need to reuse functions by just changing args.

Answer (score 2):

A purely pandas solution:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2.rename(columns = {'Product_MRD':'Product'})]).drop_duplicates(['ISIN_CUSIP_CODE'],keep='last').sort_values('ISIN_CUSIP_CODE')
```

No extra libraries required

Comment: Very nice one liner!

Comment: @Mark Warburton Great!!